# Determining conductor of a Dirichlet character

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, characters

I was reading the book *Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields by Lawrence C. Washington* and the conductor of a Dirichlet character is defined as:

[image]

An example is also given to make the definition clear.

[image]

I was wondering how can we determine the conductor of a Dirichlet character defined for a given mod $n$.

Also, if $n$ is prime, will the conductor be $n$ itself?

Comment: I believe it will be the minimal prime in the prime factorization of $n$ that isn't $2$ since the group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is trivial. Note that my username is not a credential.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then the conductor of $\chi$ is $n$, unless $\chi$ is the principal character. The principal character has conductor $1$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField For $n = 8,$ what will be the conductor according to your reasoning? (It is given in the book, the conductor is $4$ for $n=8$)

Comment: I believe this answer to my related question provides some insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3511701.

Answer (score 2):

A Dirichlet character $\bmod N$ (ie. completely multiplicative $N$ periodic function) is of the form $\psi(n) = \chi(n)1_{\gcd(n,N)=1}$ where $\chi$ is a primitive character  $\bmod d$ and $d|N,d< N$. Then $d$ is the conductor. It is the least integer $m>0$ such that $\gcd(n,N)=\gcd(n+m,N)=1\implies \psi(n+m)=\psi(n)$. Then $\chi(n) = 0$ if $\gcd(n,d)> 1$ and $\chi(n)= \psi(n+ad)$ if $\gcd(n,d)=\gcd(n+ad,N)=1$

The next step is to use the CRT to find that $\chi = \prod_j \chi_j$ where $d=\prod_j p_j^{e_j}$ and $\chi_j$ is a primitive character $\bmod p_j^{e_j}$.